# Can I adjust varistor range?

Tags: resistors

I can connect many resistor in parallel or series to get a final resistance I want in case when I have no necessary nominal out of the box.

I wonder is there such trick that will allow me to easily change varistor's nominal. Say, originally I have a varistor that changes its resistance from 0 to 200 kilohm. Can I construct a simple circuit that will map the range to, for example, 0-10 kilohm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy trick is to place a fixed resistor, say 10 kOhm, in parallel with the varistor. The total resistance will now vary between 0 and 9.5 kOhm. But the problem here is that the total resistance does not vary linearly with the varistor's resistance, f.i. when the varistor is at one quarter, at 50 kOhm, my circuit will still be at 8.3 kOhm rather than 2.5 kOhm.

If you do need linearity you'll need other, more complicated components (I'm sure that with an opamp you can simulate this).

The bigger question is though, in what circuit do you want to use this? Maybe there's an easier way to accomplish this.

(You could also place 20 of your 0-200 kOhm varistors in parallel, which also gives you 0-10 kOhm, but that doesn't seem like a very good solution to me either...)

Comment: Thanks! Now I see there is no easy (cheap) way to tweak varistor combining it with other things. Well, let it be :)

Answer (score 3):

Wim is correct with his ideas but I wanted to say that in general placing nonlinear circuit elements in parallel or series will produce undefined behavior.  Unless the two nonlinear elements are precisely matched (ie, their trip points, V-I characteristics, etc are within <1% of each other) then there's no telling what will happen exactly.

Also, are you using the term varistor here properly?  It's not usually a VARiable ResISTOR (ie, a potentiometer or rheostat) it's a nonlinear voltage protection device that acts like a circuit breaker.  If you're just working with a potentiometer or rheostat then you can add and subtract resistance in parallel or series to your heart's content and you'll get easily calculated behavior since everything combines linearly.

Comment: Yep, looks like I misused the term *Varistor*. I've meant linear potentiometer actually. Thanks for clarification.